# QLabel background issue

Tags: c++, qt, background, styles, qlabel

I'm facing a situation when I'm working with QLabels that have a style applied. Whenever I try to replace the background color, but I'm not able to do so, because it is, somehow, transparent. I'm trying not to hardcode the background, but to apply styles. Here's the code and some explanations:

```
#include "fccLabel.h"

FccLabel::FccLabel(QWidget* parent) : QLabel(parent)
{
    this->setFrameStyle(QFrame::StyledPanel);
    this->setStyleSheet("border: 2px solid gray; border-radius: 3px;");
}


void FccLabel::SetBackColor(quint32 c)
{
    QPalette        p;

    p = this->palette();
    this->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground, false);
    this->setAutoFillBackground(true);
    p.setColor(backgroundRole(), QColor(c));
    this->setPalette(p);
    this->update();
}



void FccLabel::SetTextColor(quint32 c)
{
    QPalette        p;

    p = this->palette();
    p.setColor(QPalette::WindowText, QColor(c));
    this->setPalette(p);
    this->update();
}
```

and the header file is:

```
#ifndef FCCLABEL_H
#define FCCLABEL_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QFont>

class FccLabel : public QLabel
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    FccLabel(QWidget* parent = 0);

    void    SetBackColor(quint32 c);
    void    SetTextColor(quint32 c);
};

#endif // FCCLABEL_H
```

With this code, text coloring works fine, but the Label remains transparent (unaffected). If I comment these two lines:

```
this->setFrameStyle(QFrame::StyledPanel);
this->setStyleSheet("border: 2px solid gray; border-radius: 3px;");
```

the background color changes.

I also tried doing what's next, without commenting the lines above:

```
this->setStyleSheet("background-color: Qt::red;");
```

background color changes, but, again, I loose every other style elements.

What am I doing wrong? Is there any other thing I can try?

Comment: this->setStyleSheet is applied to what object?

Comment: Is it correct to set style sheets without class? Is it correct to write `Qt` namespace in a style sheet? Try `setStyleSheet("QLabel {background-color: red;}")`. You may launch Qt Designer and test widgets with QSS there.

Comment: It is correct but is applied to all objects including that one plus children.

Comment: @ilotXXI I already tried those. On many examples on the qt.io documentation it's used this way. I also tried using RGB color entry, specific implementations (FccLabel), but still does the same.

Comment: @NEG_VMS Do you use `quint32` correctly? Consider `QRgb`, `QRgba` (which both are `quint32` type definitions and are __the same__) or `QColor`. This also may be a role issue.

Comment: Before setting the `QColor` you may check it for validity. This encsures that the problem is not located there.